# How to cover the crevice between some laminate and molding

Tags: trim, cover

There's a small (SMALL!) walkway next to this staircase that was originally covered with carpet.  It's been ripped out and replaced with laminate, but now there's a crevice between the laminate and the wall molding.  Any suggestions on how to fix or cover up?

[image: pic1]

Comment: slide the laminate so that it touches the molding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small gaps like that are often filled with white painters caulk. Be sure that it is *paintable*. Get the small tube (not the caulk gun size). Cut the nozzle size to small.

It can be squeezed into the gap and carefully wiped off the laminate with a damp paper towel.